# How to force render same id with same data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, next.js

I have some card components (soldItems, createdItems) with same data, so this mean created items and sold items both are owned by creator and displayed on his profile, i want to show soldItem if it solded and don't show createdItem if it solded ...

Example:

```
SoldItem.filter((sold)=>{
CreatedItem.filter((created)=>{
   if(sold.id === created.id){
   console.log("matched");
   // In case its matched i want to show one of them not both
}else{
   console.log("not matched")
}
})
})
```

Comment: Should the filter function be returning a boolean if the `sold` should be included in result array or not? What is the issue more specifically? Can you provide more detail context for what isn't working?

Comment: Why are you nesting filter calls? You only need to filter created. `CreatedItem.filter((created)=> !SoldItem.some(sold => sold.id === created.id));`

Comment: @Drew Reese thank you for your response, problem solved